# hamachi like software for Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, software-rec, vpn, hamachi

It looks like hamachi has halted support for Mac OSX.  Has anyone found something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [Remobo](http://www.remobo.com/) is the alternative everyone at the Hamachi forums are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [**Shimo**](http://www.chungwasoft.com/shimo/).

[image]

The latest version explicitly supports Snow Leopard.

> Shimo supports
>   almost every VPN protocol that is
>   currently used. Next to the widely
>   used CiscoVPN, Shimo easily handles
>   OpenVPN and standard compliant IPSec
>   connections. PPTP and L2TP are no
>   problem at all either. With Cisco's
>   new AnyConnect protocol and the
>   zero-configuration protocol **Hamachi**
>   the list of supported connection types
>   becomes even longer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the current version of Hamachi.

Answer (score 1):

for that very same reason, i made a copy available for public of latest hamachi build for mac os x
http://rapidshare.com/files/284206176/hamachi-0.9.9.9-20-osx.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Remobo on multiple Windows OS based systems (XP, Vista, and 7 RC 1), as well as on OS X Leopard and Snow Leopard, and have yet to get it to work once.

Answer (score 0):

People use [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com) to seamlessly connect laptops, desktops, phones, embedded devices, cloud resources, and apps any way they want anywhere they go.